# running all test suites of a project written in Scala with coverage in Intellij

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea

Is there a way to run all test suites of a project written in Scala with coverage in Intellij. Also if possible select only select specific test suites of  project and run with coverage? How about the current capabilities for the same for the Java projects?

Answer (score 1):

I think it might depend on what package you use to test. However if you use scalatest you can right-click on any package and select run tests which will run only the ones in that package.

Alternatively you can define a ScalaTest run configuration and choose tests by

- All in package
- Class
- Test name

With test name you can pick from across multiple packages (although I've never had a use for this).

Answer (score 0):

Add following line to your build.sbt file:

```
coverageEnabled := true
```

This configuration can be further refined e.g.

```
coverageEnabled in Test := true
```

And then right-click on the base package -> 'Run Scala Tests in 'xx'' with Coverage, should do it.